# How to retrieve a value from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 table to windows form TextBox's :

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I am doing a project in VB.NET.  I have a form where there are 3 text boxes and a command button.

When I enter a value into TextBox1 (which is the Registertion Number of the patient) and click on the Command Button (SearchButton) it has to search the value from my SQL Server table and give the results in TextBox2 and TextBox3 (which is Name and Age of the Patient).

This is what I did, but it is not working.

```
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=hms;Integrated Security=True"
    cn.Open()
    Dim cm As New SqlCommand
    cm.CommandText = "SELECT Patient_Name,Age FROM Patient_Prescrib"
    cm.Connection = cn
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    dr = cm.ExecuteReader

    If dr.HasRows Then

        dr.Read()
        ' TextBox1.Text = dr.Item("Reg_No")
        TextBox3.Text = dr.Item("Patient_Name")
        TextBox4.Text = dr.Item("Age")
        dr.Close()

    End If
    cn.Close()
```

Comment: **(1)**  Exact duplicate of [How to retrieve values from SQL Server Table to TextBoxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933651/how-to-retrieve-values-from-sql-server-table-to-textboxes).  **(2)** This was posted *after* I cleaned up your first question, and you still haven't explained **what's wrong**.  Don't open a new question if you don't get responses right away, that's only going to clutter up the site and irritate users.  **(3)**  This is VB.NET, not VB6, stop using the [vb6] tag.  The [microsoft] tag is not needed either.

Comment: I think you need a WHERE clause on your SQL to narrow the returned data to a single record.
WHERE Pat_ID=123456 e.g.

Comment: Looks like you need to add a where clause to your sql statement,so you can search off of the Registration Number of the patient entered. Otherwise you have no criteria to let you know what patient was brought back from the database. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what is happening. (F8)

Comment: I am sorry am new the this site. Thats why. -@LittleBobbyTables

Answer (score 0):

@SoftwareCarpenter ,@D_Bester, @rheitzman Thank You.This is what i did and got it right. :)

```
 Private Sub DetailsButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DetailsButton.Click
    Try
        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
        con.ConnectionString = "Data source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=hms;Integrated Security=True"
        con.Open()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from Patient_Prescrib WHERE Reg_No LIKE '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%'", con)
        da.Fill(dt)
        For Each DataRow In dt.Rows
            If TextBox1.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Reg_No").ToString Then

                TextBox2.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Patient_Name").ToString
                TextBox3.Text = dt.Rows(0)("Patient_Con").ToString

                MessageBox.Show("Patient details added!")
                Return
            End If
        Next
        con.Open()
        Return
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(" a run time error has occured. Please make sure you have provided the reg no for search")

    End Try

End Sub
```